# Turing machine deciding $\{1^{2^n+1} : n \geq 0 \}$

Tags: turing-machines

Plz draw. Turing machine if
Design a Turing machine in the following three ways of descriptions that decide 
the language 
L = {12n+1 : n ≥ 0},
 the language consisting of all strings of 0s in given 
exponential function.
1. The Formal description of Turing machine
2. Implementation level description of the Turing machine
3. High level description of the Turing machine
Some example words of the language are as follows:
a. 11
b. 1111
c. 11111111

Comment: Not answered that question here 2^n+1 which is differ from the last that was 2^n

Comment: The two questions are pretty similar. Adapting the answer given there to your particular case is your job.